# How to count total number of files in directories including nested folder using file extention for example '.json'

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, os.walk

**I need to count total number of .json files in directories including nested folder.**
I have tried this

```
json_file_count = 0 
for roots,dirs, files in os.walk(path)
    for json_file_count in files:
        if os.path.splitext(n)[1] == '.json'
print(json_file_count)
```

It display all the file .Json files names. I need total number of integer.
I have tried len()

```
print(len(json_file_count))
```

But Its just count the numbers of words contain in a file name :(

when I tried `json_file_count += files`

But it shows *Type error: must be str, not int*

Please help me. Any help highly appreciate it. I am desperate..... :'(

Comment: Increment `json_file_count` if the condition is satisfied and print it outside all loops at the end.

Comment: Fix your indentation errors and read up on [Tutorlial - 3.1.1. Numbers](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
json_file_count = 0 
for roots,dirs, files in os.walk(path)
    for file in files:
        if os.path.splitext(file)[1] == '.json':
            json_file_count += 1   
            
print(json_file_count)
```

---

---

The reason your code doesn't work is because, look at this:

```
for json_file_count in files:
```

You assumed that the `json_file_count` is a number, but actually, it's the name of the file. I believe what you were trying to do was

```
for json_file_count in range(1, len(files)+1):
```

which, actually, doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pathlib import Path

number_of_jsons = len(Path("path/to/dir").rglob("*.json"))
```